# Does MutationObserver observe changes to a span's offsetHeight property?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm trying to use a MutationObserver to observe when a span changes height (when the text inside of the span changes size). But no mutations seem to be raised, even though inspecting the span's offsetHeight property does show a change. Are property changes not observed?

```
let mutationobserverconfig = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
}; 

function onmutation(mutations) {

  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    log("resizemutationobserver");
    // for
  }

  // onmutation
}

let resizemutationobserver;

function addresizemutationobserver(element, callback) {

// callback is in the module using this function


  resizemutationobserver = new MutationObserver(onmutation);
  let targetnode = $(element)[0];
  resizemutationobserver.observe(targetnode, mutationobserverconfig); //

}
```

Comment: I think you want ResizeObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Comment: @AlexK Good suggestion. You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: I need to support IE 11 :-(. Caniuse shows ResizeObserver as not supported

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick how is the text in the span changing size?

Comment: There are multiple ways: via css, also via a browser's font sizing controls. I'm using the detector for some responsive designs. I had a detector working fine until the newest mobile safari, so I thought I'd try something based on MutationObserver.

Comment: Mutation observers have a pretty niche use case and it has an unwieldy API. Don't use it unless you have to. Appending a resize event listener is more than enough for your needs

Comment: @Andrew I thought resize event listener only applies to the body element? I'll need to try attaching it to the span.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick Event listeners work on whatever you decide to append it to.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried $(testspan).on("resize",event=>{console.log('resize')}); No dice.  I'll try pure vanilla js to attach the listener

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick Turns out I'm wrong. You can only append it to the window. I made the mistake in assuming that any html element can have any event listener appended to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Yeah window. I did try vanilla js just to try it. I half expected it to work in Chrome but no luck. I still have my crazy scientist hat on :-) Now I understand why NPM packages offering this functionality make use of requestanimationframe and lots of browser sniffing.

Comment: It depends on the technology you use, but if you can piggyback off of some type of update cycle (in React it would be `componentWillUpdate`), you can store the existing dimension and then compare it with the current

Comment: Oooooo I love your thinking @Andrew gonna try React right now

Comment: My last comment about this question. React's componentWillUpdate is called on setState, so even with React I'd need to use polling. Anyways, thanks for the thoughts everyone

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick, inspect the code that's causing the change and see if it makes some other side effects which you can detect.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the idea. At this point, I'm re-examining what mobile Safari is actually doing with it's "aA" resize control. I did try a solution using IntersectionObserver and it worked, but not in mobile Safari. I'll comment here with a link to an answered question when I've developed a solution.

Comment: As promised, solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313462/does-ios-mobile-safari-provide-a-javascript-event-or-a-media-query-for-its-font/58329983#58329983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this question it is important to differentiate between *attribute* and *property*.  This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/8376184) in detail.

The HTML elements have attributes, and some of them are reflected by properties of the corresponding DOM interface (node).

The interface has some additional *properties* (e.g. `offsetHeight`) which have no matching HTML attributes.

As the `MutationObserver` observes changes made to attributes, it won't monitor changes of `offsetHeight`.

---

To monitor changes of the size of an element, you can use a `ResizeObserver` instead (by now it has reached wide support).

Comment: Dang. Hmmm, now I wonder which attributes are automatically calculated when a span changes size ... perhaps style ... time for some testing.

Comment: Duh. If any attributes were changing then the MO would have observed them. Dang.

Answer (score 1):

`ResizeObserver` is the correct API to use, but if you have a `span` you'll need to set it to be an inline-block element :

```
span.some-text 
{
   display: inline-block
}
```

`block` would work too, but then it would just reflect the size of its parent container.