# Does iOS/mobile Safari provide a javascript event or a media query for its font resizing control?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari, responsive-design

A responsive website that I style uses js to determine font sizes then applies classes that are used by css for various layout adjustments. In a nutshell, my js detects the resize of a span wrapped around a text character. The newest version of mobile Safari provides a font resize control and its zoom mechanism isn't triggering my detection js. Any ideas about events or other changes that I can use to detect mobile Safari's font resizing? Maybe a css media query? I tried a solution based on js intersectionobserver: worked on desktop but not mobile :-(

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust)

> The text-size-adjust CSS property controls the text inflation
> algorithm used on some smartphones and tablets. Other browsers will
> ignore this property.

Be sure to include CSS properties such as

```
/* Keyword values */
text-size-adjust: none;
text-size-adjust: auto;

/* <percentage> value */
text-size-adjust: 80%;

/* Global values */
text-size-adjust: inherit;
text-size-adjust: initial;
text-size-adjust: unset;
```

However, only non-percentage values are supported in Safari for iOS.

---

Also, consider looking at Apple's [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#)
which explains how percentages for a text-resize factor can be used.

```
html {-webkit-text-size-adjust:200%}
```

I am not sure which one of these is correct since they conflict each other. You would have to test for yourself and see what works best for you.

PS: **Be sure to include -webkit- prefix for mentioned properties to make sure it works for safari and other WebKit browsers.**

Comment: Thanks Amrit, this is an interesting iOS feature. Upon further research I found that Bootstrap sets the html element's -webkit-text-size-adjust to 100%, meaning more font size control via custom css. That said, I'm still wondering about a method to determine when a user has used mobile Safari's font resize control so that my js can classify the current font size.

Answer (score -1):

So what mobile safari does is: when the font is enlarged, it's actually the viewport becoming narrower. There is a widely supported window.matchMedia(*media query here*) method that returns a "media query object" to which a listener can be added. In my case, I want to know when the viewport is narrower than apx. 320px ... in which case I'll apply my styling classes.